# Sorting a 2d array JavaScript by value of both columns

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

How can I quickly sort a 2d array in JavaScript according to value of both columns?

Array will appear in this format:

```
[12, 3]
[12, 2]
[54, 43]
[32, 12]
```

After sorting it should look like this:

```
[12, 2]
[12, 3]
[32, 12]
[54, 43]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Array.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and subtract the first items in the nested arrays to determine precedence. If they're equal, subtract the second items.

```js
const arr = [
  [12, 3],
  [12, 2],
  [54, 43],
  [32, 12]
]

const res = arr.sort((a,b) => a[0] - b[0] || a[1] - b[1])

console.log(res)
```

Comment: why the downvote, the code snippet is outputting the exact desired output